# How to access a file on a Client from a Server without transferring the file from the Client to the Server in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am programming my first Java Socket application that uses a Client/Server paradigm.

I have the following classes:
SocketServer
SocketClient

The objective of the application is to have a user input a file path to a .csv file on the Client Console/File System:

```
 1. Create a Server Program that uses a Socket.
 a. The Server receives a CSV path/filename located on the Client from the Client.
 b. The Server accesses the Client CSV file and converts it to an XML file.
 c. The Server streams the XML file contents, not the XML path/file
 name, back to the Client.
```

> Create a Client Program that uses a Socket. Use the same port as the
>   Server.
>
> a. Prompt the user for the path/filename of a CSV file.
>
> b. Send the path/filename to the Server for processing.
>
> c. Receive the XML file stream from the Server Socket.
>
> d. Save the XML file stream to a file stored on the Client.
>
> e. Store the generated XML file anywhere on the Client.

I have already written the code for connecting the Sockets on both the Server and Client as well as for converting the .csv to .xml, however, I am struggling with:

> Step 1b.The Server accesses the Client CSV file and converts it to an
>   XML file.

Can I access the .csv file located on the Client directly from the Server
OR
Do I have to transfer the file path back from the Server to the Client, then transfer the file to the Server for conversion, then transfer the new XML document back?

Based on the instructions, it sounds like there should be a way to access the file from the Server.

Here is the code that I have already written.

ClientController.java

```
public class ClientController extends ConsoleController {

    // DEBUG
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_STORE = false;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_PROMPT = false;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_VALUES = true;

    // CONSTANTS
    public static final String PROMPT_MESSAGE = "Enter the filepath to a '.csv' file to convert to a '.xml' file: ";

    // MEMBERS
    private String userFilepath;
    private SocketClient mClient;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public ClientController() {
        super();
        mClient = null;
    }

    // LIFE-CYCLE METHODS
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // Setup the Connection to the Server
        mClient = setupServerConnection();

        // Get the path to the CSV file for conversion
        requestPathToCSVFile();

        // Attempt to Transfer the file
        try {
            sendPathToServer(userFilepath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to transfer the file!");
            System.out.println("Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Attempt to send some message 50 times
        mClient.sendSomeMessages(3);
    }

    // CONVENIENCE METHODS
    private SocketClient setupServerConnection() {
        String hostname = "localhost";
        int port = 54321;
        byte[] data = "Hello Server".getBytes();

        return new SocketClient(hostname, port, data);
    }

    private void requestPathToCSVFile() {
        // Debug vars
        boolean isEmpty = true;
        boolean isDefaultMessage = true;
        boolean isCSV = false;

        while (true){

            if (!isEmpty && !isDefaultMessage && isCSV) break;

            // Prompt user
            userFilepath = promptUser(PROMPT_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(userFilepath);
            // Debugging
            isEmpty = userFilepath.isEmpty();
            isDefaultMessage = userFilepath.equals(DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
            isCSV = isCSVPath(userFilepath);


            // Output Debugging
            if (DEBUG && DEBUG_VALUES) {
                if (userFilepath != null) {
                    System.out.println("DEBUG userFilepath: " + userFilepath);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("DEBUG userFilepath: isNull");
                }
                System.out.println("isEmpty: " + (isEmpty? "true":"false"));
                System.out.println("DEBUG userFilepath:" + (isDefaultMessage? "true":"false"));
                System.out.println("isCSVPath: " + (isCSVPath(userFilepath)? "true":"false"));
            }

        }
    }
    private void sendPathToServer(String path) {
        // Send the filepath to the Server
        mClient.sendMessage(path);
    }

    private boolean isCSVPath(String path) {
        return Regex.hasExtension(path, "csv");
    }
}
```

SocketServer.java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

// An example of a very simple socket server.  
public class SocketServer 
{
    // CONSTANTS
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_NODES = true;

    // FLAGS
    private static final int FLAG_MESSAGE = 0;
    private static final int FLAG_CONVERT_CSV_TO_XML = 1;

    // CONSTANTS
    private static final String TEMPORARY_FOLDER_PATH = "/tmp";
    private static final String TEMP_CSV_FILENAME = "csvToConvertToXml.csv";
    private static final String TEMP_XML_FILENAME = "xmlOfCsv.xml";

    // MEMBERS
    private int serverPort;
    private ServerSocket mServerSocket = null;
    private Socket mSocket;
    private InputStream mSocketInput;
    private OutputStream mSocketOutput;
    private int mSocketFlag;
    private String mPathToCsv;


    public SocketServer(int serverPort) 
    {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;

        try 
        {
            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }


    public void waitForConnections() 
    {

        mSocket = null;
        mSocketInput = null;
        mSocketOutput = null;
        while (true) 
        {
            // Open a Socket on the Server and Wait for a Connection
            openSocket();

            // TODO CODE THE FLAGGING
            mSocketFlag = 1;

            switch (mSocketFlag) {
                case FLAG_MESSAGE:
                    handleConnection();
                break;
                case FLAG_CONVERT_CSV_TO_XML:
                    handleFileConversionConnection();
                break;
            }

            // Now close the socket.
            closeSocket();
        }
    }

    // All this method does is wait for some bytes from the
    // connection, read them, then write them back again, until the
    // socket is closed from the other side.
    public void handleFileConversionConnection() 
    {
        while(true) 
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes_read = 0;
            try 
            {
                // This call to read() will wait forever, until the
                // program on the other side either sends some data,
                // or closes the socket.
                bytes_read = mSocketInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                // If the socket is closed, sockInput.read() will return -1.
                if(bytes_read < 0) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Tried to read from socket, read() returned < 0,  Closing socket.");
                    return;
                }

                // Set the mPathToCsv
                mPathToCsv = new String(buffer, 0, bytes_read);

                // Log the RECIEVED DATA
                System.out.println("Server Received "+ bytes_read +" bytes, data=" + mPathToCsv);
                System.out.println("mPathToCsv: " + mPathToCsv);


                // Get the a the path supplied by the Client and save it in the /temp folder on the server
                String pathToTempCsv = getFileFromClient(mPathToCsv,TEMPORARY_FOLDER_PATH, TEMP_CSV_FILENAME);

                // Convert the Csv to XML
                String pathToXmlForClient = convertCsvToXml(pathToTempCsv, TEMPORARY_FOLDER_PATH, TEMP_XML_FILENAME);

                // Transfer the new XML Document to the Client
                //transfer(pathToXmlForClient);

                // 
                mSocketOutput.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
                // This call to flush() is optional - we're saying go
                // ahead and send the data now instead of buffering it.
                mSocketOutput.flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Exception reading from/writing to socket, e="+e);
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // All this method does is wait for some bytes from the
        // connection, read them, then write them back again, until the
        // socket is closed from the other side.
        public void handleConnection() 
        {
            while(true) 
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytes_read = 0;
                try 
                {
                    // This call to read() will wait forever, until the
                    // program on the other side either sends some data,
                    // or closes the socket.
                    bytes_read = mSocketInput.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    // If the socket is closed, sockInput.read() will return -1.
                    if(bytes_read < 0) 
                    {
                        System.err.println("Tried to read from socket, read() returned < 0,  Closing socket.");
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Server Received "+ bytes_read +" bytes, data=" + (new String(buffer, 0, bytes_read)));
                    mSocketOutput.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
                    // This call to flush() is optional - we're saying go
                    // ahead and send the data now instead of buffering it.
                    mSocketOutput.flush();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Exception reading from/writing to socket, e="+e);
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }



    public void openSocket() {
        try 
        {
            // This method call, accept(), blocks and waits
            // (forever if necessary) until some other program
            // opens a socket connection to our server.  When some
            // other program opens a connection to our server,
            // accept() creates a new socket to represent that
            // connection and returns.
            mSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("Have accepted new socket.");

            // From this point on, no new socket connections can
            // be made to our server until accept() is called again.
            mSocketInput = mSocket.getInputStream();
            mSocketOutput = mSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public void closeSocket() {
        try 
        {
            System.err.println("Closing socket.");
            mSocket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception while closing socket.");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        System.err.println("Finished with socket, waiting for next connection.");
    }


    // CONVENIENCE METHODS
    public void transfer(String sfile) throws IOException {
        if (DEBUG && DEBUG_NODES) System.out.println("Enter transfer(String sfile)");

        // Create a new File object
        File myFile = new File(sfile);
        while (true) {

            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            // Get the OutputStream for the Socket
            mSocketOutput.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            mSocketOutput.flush();

            // Close the socket
            bis.close();
        }
    }

    public String getFileFromClient(String pathToFile, String destinationDirectory, String newFilename) {
        if (DEBUG && DEBUG_NODES) System.out.println("Enter getFileFromClient(String pathToFile, String destinationDirectory, String newFilename)");
        String pathToNewFile = destinationDirectory + "/" + newFilename;
        // TODO GET THE FILE FROM THE CLIENT


        if (DEBUG && DEBUG_NODES) System.out.println("Exit getFileFromClient(String pathToFile, String destinationDirectory, String newFilename)");
        return pathToNewFile;
    }

    public String convertCsvToXml(String pathToCsv, String pathToDestinationDirectory, String newFilename) {
        if (DEBUG && DEBUG_NODES) System.out.println("Enter convertCsvToXml(String pathToCsv, String pathToDestinationDirectory, String newFilename)");
        String pathToNewFile = pathToDestinationDirectory + "/" + newFilename;
        // TODO CREATE THE NEW FILE AND CONVERT THE CSV TO XML
        XMLWriter xmlFile = new XMLWriter(pathToCsv, pathToNewFile);
        xmlFile.csvToXml();

        if (DEBUG && DEBUG_NODES) System.out.println("Exit convertCsvToXml(String pathToCsv, String pathToDestinationDirectory, String newFilename)");
        return pathToNewFile;
    }


    public static void main(String argv[]) 
    {
        int port = 54321;
        SocketServer server = new SocketServer(port);
        server.waitForConnections();
    }
}
```

SocketClient.java

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketClient 
{
    // CONSTANTS
    public static final int TRANSFER_SIZE_1KB = 1024;

    // MEMBERS
    private String mServerHostname = null;
    private int mServerPort = 0;
    private byte[] data = null;
    private Socket mSocket = null;
    private InputStream mSocketInput = null;
    private OutputStream mSocketOutput = null;

    public SocketClient(String ServerHostname, int ServerPort)
    {
        this(ServerHostname, ServerPort, null);
    }

    public SocketClient(String mServerHostname, int mServerPort, byte[] data)
    {
        this.mServerHostname =  mServerHostname;
        this.mServerPort = mServerPort;
        this.data = data;
    }


    public void transfer( String outfile ) throws Exception {

        // Open the Socket
        openSocket();

        // Create a new byte array size of 1KB
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[TRANSFER_SIZE_1KB];

        // Create a bufferedOutputStream from the outfile path
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        // TESTING
        fos.toString();

        // Initialize values to 0
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("GOT HERE");

        // Transfer the 'outfile' 1KB (1024 bytes) increments, each pass is 1KB chunk of files
        while ((bytesRead = mSocketInput.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length)) != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("GOT HERE");
            // Send the data to the Server
            bos.write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead);
            // If less than 1KB, finish the transfer using flush()
            bos.flush();
            System.out.println(++count);
        }

        // Log to console
        System.out.println("Finished transferring " + outfile);

        // Close the bufferedOutputStream
        bos.close();

        // Close the socket
        closeSocket();
    }



    public void sendSomeMessages(int iterations) 
    {
        // Open the Socket
        openSocket();

        byte[] buf = new byte[data.length];
        int bytes_read = 0;
        for(int x=1; x<=iterations; x++) 
        {
            try 
            {
                mSocketOutput.write(data, 0, data.length); 
                bytes_read = mSocketInput.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            if( bytes_read != data.length ) 
            {
                System.out.println("run: Sent "+ data.length +" bytes, server should have sent them back, read "+bytes_read+" bytes, not the same number of bytes.");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Client Sent "+bytes_read+" bytes to server and received them back again, msg = "+(new String(data)));
            }

            // Sleep for a bit so the action doesn't happen to fast - 
            // this is purely for reasons of demonstration, and not required technically.
            try { Thread.sleep(50);}
            catch (Exception e) {}; 
        }
        System.err.println("Done reading/writing to/from socket, closing socket.");

        // Close the Socket
        closeSocket();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String str) {
        // Open the Socket
        openSocket();

        // Convert the String to a Byte Array
        byte[] data = str.getBytes();

        // Create a buffer object the size of the data byte array
        byte[] buf = new byte[data.length];
        int bytes_read = 0;

        // Attempt to send the data over the network
            try 
            {
                mSocketOutput.write(data, 0, data.length); 
                bytes_read = mSocketInput.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            if( bytes_read != data.length ) 
            {
                System.out.println("run: Sent "+ data.length +" bytes, server should have sent them back, read "+bytes_read+" bytes, not the same number of bytes.");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Client Sent "+bytes_read+" bytes to server and received them back again, msg = "+(new String(data)));
            }

            // Sleep for a bit so the action doesn't happen to fast - 
            // this is purely for reasons of demonstration, and not required technically.
            try { Thread.sleep(50);}
            catch (Exception e) {}; 

        System.err.println("Done reading/writing to/from socket, closing socket.");

        // Close the Socket
        closeSocket();
    }

    public void openSocket() {
        // Open the Socket
        System.err.println("Opening connection to "+mServerHostname+" port "+mServerPort);
        try 
        {
            mSocket = new Socket(mServerHostname, mServerPort);
            mSocketInput = mSocket.getInputStream();
            mSocketOutput = mSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            return;
        }

        System.err.println("About to start reading/writing to/from socket.");
    }

    public void closeSocket() {
        // Close the Socket
        try 
        {
            mSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception closing socket.");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        System.err.println("Exiting.");
    }


    // GETTERS & SETTERS
    public String getServerHostname() {
        return mServerHostname;
    }



    public void setServerHostname(String serverHostname) {
        this.mServerHostname = mServerHostname;
    }



    public int getServerPort() {
        return mServerPort;
    }



    public void setServerPort(int serverPort) {
        this.mServerPort = mServerPort;
    }



    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }



    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.mSocket = mSocket;
    }



    public InputStream getSocketInput() {
        return mSocketInput;
    }



    public void setSocketInput(InputStream socketInput) {
        this.mSocketInput = mSocketInput;
    }



    public OutputStream getSocketOutput() {
        return mSocketOutput;
    }



    public void setSocketOutput(OutputStream socketOutput) {
        this.mSocketOutput = mSocketOutput;
    }


}
```

SUPPORTING CLASSES

ConsoleController.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Comparator;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public abstract class ConsoleController {

    // DEBUG
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_STORE = false;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_PROMPT = false;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_VALUES = false;

    // CONSTANTS
    protected static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "No input recieved";


    // MEMBERS
    private String mRecentInput;


    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public ConsoleController() {
        mRecentInput = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    }


    // LIFE-CYCLE METHODS
    abstract public void onCreate();

    public String promptUser(String userPrompt) {
        System.out.println(userPrompt);

        try{
            // Create BufferedReader to read from the Console
            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            // Read the line from the console
            mRecentInput = bufferRead.readLine();
            if (mRecentInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) exit();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mRecentInput;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return mRecentInput;
    }

    public void exit() {
        //System.out.println("Quiting");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Regex.java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Regex {

    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    public static final boolean DEBUG_HAS_EXT = true;

    public static boolean hasExtension(String path, String extension) {

        // Match Numberic and Hexadecimal Values
        Pattern extTest = Pattern.compile("\\.(" + extension.trim() + ")$"); 
        Matcher values = extTest.matcher(path);

        if (DEBUG && DEBUG_HAS_EXT) {
            System.out.println("Regex - Extension Matches");
            System.out.println("Search String: " + path);
            System.out.println("Pattern: " + extTest.pattern());
            System.out.print("Match: ");
        }

        // Returns true if there is anotherMatch remaining, returns false if no matches remain
        boolean anotherMatch = values.find();

        if (anotherMatch == true) {
            while(anotherMatch) {

                // If we get here, there is a match
                // Log
                if (DEBUG && DEBUG_HAS_EXT) System.out.println(values.group());

                // Check to see if there is anotherMatch
                anotherMatch = values.find();
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            if (DEBUG && DEBUG_HAS_EXT) System.out.println("There was no match");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

XMLWriter.java

```
import java.io.*;


import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*; 

public class XMLWriter
{   
    // Members
    private Document mDocumentForOutput;
    private String mInFilePath;
    private String mOutFilePath;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public XMLWriter(String filePathForConversion, String filePathForOutput) {
        mInFilePath = filePathForConversion;
        mOutFilePath = filePathForOutput;
        try {
            mDocumentForOutput = createDocument();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public Document createDocument() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        return doc;
    }

    public void processDocument(String delimeter) throws Exception
    {
        // Get a File object from the InPath
        File inFile  = new File(mInFilePath);

        // Create a BufferedReader from the file
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));

        // Read a line from the file
        String sline = reader.readLine();

        //
        String[] sheaders = sline.split(delimeter);
        sline = reader.readLine();
        String[] snodes = sline.split(delimeter);
        Element aroot;
        Element achild;
        aroot = mDocumentForOutput.createElement(sheaders[0].trim());
        mDocumentForOutput.appendChild(aroot);
        while ((sline=reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {           
            achild = mDocumentForOutput.createElement(sheaders[1].trim());
            String[] sdata = sline.split(delimeter);
            for (int x=0; x<snodes.length; ++x)
            {
                Element c = mDocumentForOutput.createElement(snodes[x].trim());  
                c.appendChild(mDocumentForOutput.createTextNode(sdata[x].trim()));
                achild.appendChild(c);
            }
            aroot.appendChild(achild);
        }       
    }

    public void createXML() throws Exception
    {
        //TransformerFactory instance is used to create Transformer objects. 
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        // create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(mDocumentForOutput);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();
        File file = new File(mOutFilePath);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));
        bw.write(xmlString);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();     
    }

    public void createXmlDocument(String delimeter) throws Exception 
    {
        processDocument(delimeter);
        createXML();
    }

    public void csvToXml() {
        try {
            createXmlDocument(",");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void testWriter(String csvFile)
    {
        try
        {
            try {
            XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(csvFile, "Output.xml");
            xmlWriter.csvToXml();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("'" + csvFile + "' does not exist in the given directory! Please check that you have properly entered your filepath");
            }
            System.out.println("<b>Xml File Created Successfully</b>");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The terminology you are using is a bit confusing I think. The client should send the file to the server and receive it changed. The server accessing a file on the Client makes the client act like a server and is unnecessary. Simplify the program's logic is my suggestion.

Comment: I agree, this was just the wording of my assignment.